# Pre-designed VB.NET forms?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms, visual-studio-2013

I find myself creating many forms for my application. Some are simple messageboxes, some are inputboxes and some have more controls. I find myself spending a lot of time and effort making all the controls line up and things like that. But I'm thinking that I'm reinventing something that thousands have done before me.

Is there any way I can insert ready-made pre-designed forms into my VS 2013 VB.NET project?

Comment: Right click on the solution explorer select 'Add>Existing Item' and browse to the forms .vb file

Comment: project > add existing item, and modify where necessary?

Comment: That's just what I am looking for! Do you know a site where I can donwload good ready-made pre-designed forms as items?

Comment: Why don't you create your own template and inherit it in all your forms?

Comment: Yes. since you already create many forms, you can just reuse it all and make it as your templates.

Comment: That is a pretty good idea and definitely an acceptable solution. But I also have several form designs left to do (for example an information popup with a checkbox that let's the user not see the message again). I'm thinking it would be great if I could download a library of ready-made forms from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I found pre-designed forms under Add>New>Forms>Here they were.

Previously I had only added items from Add>New>